# how to apply css and js dynamically

Tags: css, xml-parsing

i have One xml file which contain some css and script links i want to apply this dynamically on page load i want to do this on page load please help?

```
xml File---


<template>
<theme id="1" name="default">
<css>
<name>css/style.css</name>
<name>css/normalize.css</name>
<name>css/grid.css</name>
<name>css/prettyPhoto.css</name>
</css>
<js>
<name>js/jquery.easing.1.3.js</name>
 <name>js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js</name>
 <name>js/js.js</name>
 <name>js/jquery.stellar.min.js</name>
 <name>js/waypoints.min.js</name>
</js>
</theme>
</template>
```

i have done this using jquery but the problem is when i adding debugger between 
script and execute code step by step using firebug css and js applying and 
without debugger loading in head but not applying can anyOne suggest 
Xml File---

```
 jquery Code implemented in aspx file



<script src="templates/1/jquery.xml2json.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//debugger
$.get('templates/1/SettingBasic2.xml', function (xml) {
var newTemplate = $.xml2json(xml);
$(newTemplate).each(function (key, data) {
$(window).load(function () {
switch (data.theme['name']) {
default:
$(data.theme['css']['name']).each(function (key_css, css) {
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + css + '" type="text/css" media="all" />');
  });
  val = '';
  $(data.theme['js']['name']).each(function (key_js, js) {
  val += '<script type="text/javascript" src="' + js + '"></\script>';
  });
  $('head').append(val);
  break;
  }
     });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: you should be tagging more and precise topics, thats no way close to css tag

Comment: i have parse and applied this using jquery but now my requirement to do the same in page load using c#.

Answer (score 0):

i would like to say that you should use JS instead use, loadCSS.js for loading dynamic css, with control where to put what and also you can listen for when it gets loaded. 
For scripts use $script.js which is smallest lib you can find or use require js which is the best for these stuff, but overkill for just loading scripts.